# How to get rid of added column after groupby operation in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In a loop over a dataframe,  I assign a temporary variable and use with it the groupby function:

```
df[z[j]].groupby(df['Date'].dt.date).first()
```

The problem is that this operation adds another 'Date' column:

```
             Date
Date
2019-07-15   2019-07-15 07:00:00
2019-07-19   2019-07-19 11:50:00
2019-07-25   2019-07-25 09:05:00
2019-07-31   2019-07-31 07:15:00
2019-08-08   2019-08-08 07:00:00
```

unfortunately this line of code inside of the loop after the groupby operation doesn't work :

```
z[j].drop(z[j].columns[[0]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I get an error:

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'
```

How can I get rid of the first 'Date' column?

Comment: Use `df[z[j]].groupby(df['Date'].dt.date).first().reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: @jezrael Now the first column has the index numbers. Do you know how to change the code so that I also get rid of the index numbers? That the 2nd 'Date' column is the first.

Comment: Sure, use `df[z[j]].groupby(df['Date'].dt.date).first().rename_axis('date1').reset_index()`

Comment: this doesn't change it

Comment: sorry, do you need it if write to file? Because by default each DataFrame has to contains index.

Comment: I've got it by adding `.set_index('Date')`and now  I have the Date as index.